# What does the ATOLL programming language look like?

Tags: apollo-program, history, saturn-v, testing, saturn-i

During the Apollo program, checkout tests of launch vehicle and spacecraft systems were gradually being automated, moving away from the manual processes during the early years of the space program to (almost) fully automated tests by the time of Apollo 11.

One interesting problem NASA faced was how to make sure that the computer programmers (who wrote the checkout test computer programs) and the test and design engineers (who defined the checkout test procedures) understood each other:

> In the evolution of automatic checkout equipment, one of the most interesting problems centered on the creation of a new language. The language tapes incorporated in the computer programs had to be functional for the designer of the vehicle as well as the test engineer. Readouts on malfunctions had to make sense to persons reworking the piece of hardware that failed or had not performed properly. [...]

> Test engineers were putting new demands on the computers, and these new demands as well as the style of language had to be communicated to the programmer. To arrive at an appropriate language, either the test engineer had to learn more about programming, or the programmer had to learn more about test engineering. The solution to this dilemma was ATOLL, an acronym for Acceptance Test or Launch Language, designed to bridge many of the gaps between the test engineer, the designer of the stage, and the computer programmer. Originating in late 1963, ATOLL eased confusion and helped to normalize the many functions of automatic test and checkout encountered at the manufacturer's plant, during static firing, and during operations at the launch site.

(source: *[Stages to Saturn, chapter 8](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4206/ch8.htm)*)

Given the important role ATOLL played in the success of the Saturns, I'm curious to know what it looked like, and how much "high level" it actually was. However, I'm unable to find any information on it. This is the [Wikipedia article on ATOLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATOLL_(programming_language)) in its entirety:

> Acceptance, Test Or Launch Language (ATOLL) was the programming language used for automating the checking and launch of Saturn rockets.

With one reference:

1. "SLCC ATOLL User's Manual", *IBM 70-F11-0001*, Huntsville, Ala. Dec 1970

This report is not available on [NTRS](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/search?q=%22IBM%2070-F11-0001%22), and putting this reference into e.g. Google just yields and endless list of mirrors of Wikipedia (?).

I found one reference to ATOLL in [Appendix 3](https://history.nasa.gov/computers/Appendix-III.html) on GOAL of ["Computers in Spaceflight: The NASA Experience"](https://history.nasa.gov/computers/contents.html):

> GOAL is a high-level language that uses the terminology of test engineers to write tests and procedures to certify that a Shuttle vehicle is ready for launch. When the first automated preflight checkout programs were written in the mid-1960s, Marshall Space Flight Center originated ATOLL, a special high-level language for use in preparing test procedures. GOAL superseded that language in the early 1970s.

This appendix has a snippet of GOAL code and I'm guessing that GOAL resembles ATOLL, but that is no more than a hunch.

**Question:** what does ATOLL code look like? Are there listings or a reference manual available?

Comment: I have not been able to figure out what GOAL is an acronym for. Totally ungoogleable.

Comment: Some discussion of ATOLL in Moonport: A History of Apollo Launch Facilities and Operations
By Charles D. Benson, William Barnaby Faherty (on Google Books), but no code given there. Also a short blurb in Encyclopedia of Computer Science and Technology: Volume 18 - Supplement 3 ...
edited by Allen Kent, James G. Williams, also Google Books, no code.

Comment: GOAL appears to be 'Ground Operations Aerospace Language' - see https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.5555/800124.804003 - this paper has some ATOLL statements to compare with the GOAL equivalent.

Comment: [Chrome extension NASA Acronyms](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nasa-acronyms/anpbkdhjbebjjkgdbglbcfaenjldbinf) says GOAL is '*Ground Operations Aerospace Language*' or '*Ground Operations and Launch*'

Comment: GOAL documentation such as https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19740007776/downloads/19740007776.pdf seems more available

Comment: @JonCuster Can you cite some relevant sections from that paper? It is behind a paywall and unavailable to me.

Comment: @JonCuster  I'm currently reading Moonport and that triggered the question. But I thought that the Stages to Saturn quote was more relevant.

Comment: There's a good example of the use of GOAL in *Space Shuttle Technical Conference Vol 1* - "Automatic software for Controlling Cryogenic Systems". https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19850008580/downloads/19850008580.pdf  I think by the end of the program it had been moved to PCs and was called PC-GOAL, but it was a KSC thing and I never dealt with it.

Comment: There may be some folks over on Retrocomputing that may remember ATOLL - the chat room looks pretty poorly attended, so not quite sure how to poke some of the regulars over there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The documentation for the Ground Operations Aerospace Language is much more available - search at ntrs.nasa.gov and a variety of reports come up.

An [ACM publication](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.5555/800124.804003) (which apparently is not a journal article, since Web Of Science does not find it - perhaps a conference proceedings not indexed - indeed, from DAC '73: Proceedings of the 10th Design Automation Workshop June 1973, pp 87–96) by Terry R. Mitchell in the Launch Vehicle Checkout Automation and Programming Office at KSC, is titled

> A Standard Test Language - GOAL
>
> Ground Operations Aerospace Language

It mainly discusses GOAL, but touches on ATOLL. This includes several figures with comparisons between GOAL and ATOLL to do the same thing. This is done in Figure 3, shown here:

[image]

Further search has found an article in the April 1965 issue of [Datamation](http://www.bitsavers.org/magazines/Datamation/196504.pdf) (pages 33-35) which appears to lay out the language op codes completely, separated into Stimulation, Response, Control, and Utility commands. For example, Table 1 (Simulation Operators) looks like:

[image]

As an aside, the June 1965 issue (the 196506.pdf from the bitsavers archive) has a letter from B.L Ryle with some credits to various folks for the development of ATOLL.

Comment: Wow, that *Datamation* is amazing to look through. Thanks for posting the link. The source article is a great find, but the ads and such are incredible.

Comment: That Datamation issue is amazing. How/where did you find it?

Comment: @Ludo - since Web of Science did not index the Mitchell paper, I went to ACM.org and did a search for 'ATOLL'. That search brought up a paper on another acceptance testing language which referenced the Datamation article, fortunately including the title in the reference for their search engine to find. Searching for a Datamation archive lead to the bitsavers site, and ultimately to the issue - I found a link to the June issue, and fortunately bitsavers has a straightforward URL format so when I changed 196506 in the original link to 196504 up popped April...

Comment: @OrganicMarble - indeed, I could easily be sucked into a black hole going through old issues. I'll note that the author of the Datamation article is from Mesa Scientific, which has an ad a few pages up in the pdf (but actually page 91) talking about testing for Saturn and Mariner.

Comment: I also saw an ad (cut off) hiring for a contractor at Johnson Space Center.

Comment: @OrganicMarble "Speeds up to 333 characters per second" (ad on page 18). Wow! Blazing! The computer world sure has come a long, long way since 1965.

Comment: @DavidHammen - while the hardware has changed, most of the basic issues discussed are still around...

Comment: And how about that full page ad about the Phoencian programmer "Unfortunately, she was so vain that all the time she was
supposed to be tending to business, she'd be fooling
around admiring herself, dreaming of a movie career
and all that." That..didn't age well.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - oh, it is a look back to the Mad Men area, that is for sure. Cringe-worthy in oh so many ways.